# Simple table in R

Tags: r

How would I create a simple table in R with two columns and 5 rows? I currently have the following loop:

```
for (i in 0:5) {
  red <- sprintf("%d white balls and not the red ball: %f",i,win_balls(i, TRUE))
  not_red <- sprintf("%d white balls and the red ball: %f",i,win_balls(i, FALSE))
  print(not_red)
  print(red)
}
```

Instead of printing `not_red` and `red` I'd like to store them each in a respective column in a table. So the table would like like this:

```
Not Red  Red
0        2
1        3
4        5
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` to create that as a matrix:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(0:5, function(i) {
  c(i, i*2)
}))
```

Or `t(sapply())`:

```
t(sapply(0:5, function(i) {
  c(i, i*2)
}))
```

Then you just have to set the column names.

For your `win_balls` function, probably this would work

```
balls <- do.call(rbind, lapply(0:5, function(i) {
  c(win_balls(i, TRUE), win_balls(i, FALSE))
}))
colnames(balls) <- c("NotRed", "Red")
```